# Annotation in 3d matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

This is a definition for recognizing human's face in 3D. I want to annotate for all points but have no Idea. does anyone have an idea? thanks!

```
def line_up_landmarks(landmarks, ax, i):
ax.scatter(landmarks[i][:, 0], landmarks[i][:, 1], landmarks[i][:, 2], c='b', s=10)  # plot landmarks in points
ax.plot(landmarks[i][0:17, 0], landmarks[i][0:17, 1], landmarks[i][0:17, 2], c='b') # 0 - 16 face
ax.plot(landmarks[i][17:22, 0], landmarks[i][17:22, 1], landmarks[i][17:22, 2], c='b') # 17 - 21 left eyebrow
ax.plot(landmarks[i][22:27, 0], landmarks[i][22:27, 1], landmarks[i][22:27, 2], c='b') # 22 - 26 right eyebrow
ax.plot(landmarks[i][27:31, 0], landmarks[i][27:31, 1], landmarks[i][27:31, 2], c='b') # 27 - 30 nose bridge
ax.plot(landmarks[i][31:36, 0], landmarks[i][31:36, 1], landmarks[i][31:36, 2], c='b') # 31 - 35 nose wings
ax.plot(np.append(landmarks[i][36:42, 0], landmarks[i][36, 0]), np.append(landmarks[i][36:42, 1], landmarks[i][36, 1]), np.append(landmarks[i][36:42, 2], landmarks[i][36, 2]), c='b') # 36 - 41 left eye
ax.plot(np.append(landmarks[i][42:48, 0], landmarks[i][42, 0]), np.append(landmarks[i][42:48, 1], landmarks[i][42, 1]), np.append(landmarks[i][42:48, 2], landmarks[i][42, 2]), c='b') # 42 - 47 right eye
ax.plot(np.append(landmarks[i][48:60, 0], landmarks[i][48, 0]), np.append(landmarks[i][48:60, 1], landmarks[i][48, 1]), np.append(landmarks[i][48:60, 2], landmarks[i][48, 2]), c='b')# 48 - 59 outer lip
ax.plot(np.append(landmarks[i][60:68, 0], landmarks[i][60, 0]), np.append(landmarks[i][60:68, 1], landmarks[i][60, 1]), np.append(landmarks[i][60:68, 2], landmarks[i][60, 2]), c='b')# 60 - 67 inner lip

ax.plot(landmarks[i][30:32, 0], landmarks[i][30:32, 1], landmarks[i][30:32, 2], c='b') # nose bridge to right wing
ax.plot([landmarks[i][30, 0], landmarks[i][35, 0]], [landmarks[i][30, 1], landmarks[i][35, 1]], [landmarks[i][30, 2], landmarks[i][35, 2]], c='b') # nose bridge to left wing
```

Comment: You could start by reading the Matplotlib's Annotations documentation a little (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/annotations.html). As far as I know you can only make one annotation at a time, but of course, before calling the `plt.show()` statement, you could iterate through the data points you want to annotate and make the annotations individually. The reason I don't post an answer is because I don't have a full understanding of your question. I hope you find my comment useful.

Comment: (Tip: you could show what you have tried, and give us an example data for `landmarks` so we can test if the answer is correct)